# It seems that <hr> creates newlines

Tags: html

Does "hr" element create new lines similarly like paragraphs elements "p" ? Because I added an "hr" element to my table element and it gives a result like in this image :

[image]

EDIT :

```
<fieldset style="border: solid 1px "><legend>alertes offres/demandes</legend>
<div><a href="service.php?action=ServiceAjouterAlerteOD"><img src="http://localhost/bazarmada/pages/img/icons/plus.png" alt="Ajouter un alerte d'abonnement" /></a></div>
<div style="background-color:#cafbb7;"><b>March&eacute; : </b>Ambalavao</div>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="25%">Mardi</td>
        <td align="center" width="60%">Akotry</td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" value="12" checked onchange="aboDesabo($(this), $(this).val(), 'Akotry');" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><a href="service.php?action=ServiceAjouterAlerteOD&id=12"><img src="http://localhost/bazarmada/pages/img/icons/edit.png" alt="Modifier" style="height:10px;width:10px;" /></a></td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><a id="a_del" href="#" onclick="ask(12);"><img src="http://localhost/bazarmada/pages/img/icons/cross.png" alt="Supprimer" style="height:10px;width:10px;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="25%"></td>
        <td align="center" width="60%">Akotry gasy</td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" value="13"  onchange="aboDesabo($(this), $(this).val(), 'Akotry gasy');" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><a href="service.php?action=ServiceAjouterAlerteOD&id=13"><img src="http://localhost/bazarmada/pages/img/icons/edit.png" alt="Modifier" style="height:10px;width:10px;" /></a></td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><a id="a_del" href="#" onclick="ask(13);"><img src="http://localhost/bazarmada/pages/img/icons/cross.png" alt="Supprimer" style="height:10px;width:10px;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="25%"></td>
        <td align="center" width="60%">Akotry sebota</td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" value="14"  onchange="aboDesabo($(this), $(this).val(), 'Akotry sebota');" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><a href="service.php?action=ServiceAjouterAlerteOD&id=14"><img src="http://localhost/bazarmada/pages/img/icons/edit.png" alt="Modifier" style="height:10px;width:10px;" /></a></td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><a id="a_del" href="#" onclick="ask(14);"><img src="http://localhost/bazarmada/pages/img/icons/cross.png" alt="Supprimer" style="height:10px;width:10px;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="25%"></td>
        <td align="center" width="60%">Akotry tsipala</td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" value="15" checked onchange="aboDesabo($(this), $(this).val(), 'Akotry tsipala');" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><a href="service.php?action=ServiceAjouterAlerteOD&id=15"><img src="http://localhost/bazarmada/pages/img/icons/edit.png" alt="Modifier" style="height:10px;width:10px;" /></a></td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><a id="a_del" href="#" onclick="ask(15);"><img src="http://localhost/bazarmada/pages/img/icons/cross.png" alt="Supprimer" style="height:10px;width:10px;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div style="background-color:#cafbb7;"><b>March&eacute; : </b>Merimandroso</div>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="25%">Lundi</td>
        <td align="center" width="60%">Peta kofehy</td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" value="11" checked onchange="aboDesabo($(this), $(this).val(), 'Peta kofehy');" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><a href="service.php?action=ServiceAjouterAlerteOD&id=11"><img src="http://localhost/bazarmada/pages/img/icons/edit.png" alt="Modifier" style="height:10px;width:10px;" /></a></td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><a id="a_del" href="#" onclick="ask(11);"><img src="http://localhost/bazarmada/pages/img/icons/cross.png" alt="Supprimer" style="height:10px;width:10px;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="5"><hr /></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="25%">Jeudi</td>
        <td align="center" width="60%">Rary penjy</td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><input type="checkbox" value="19" checked onchange="aboDesabo($(this), $(this).val(), 'Rary penjy');" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><a href="service.php?action=ServiceAjouterAlerteOD&id=19"><img src="http://localhost/bazarmada/pages/img/icons/edit.png" alt="Modifier" style="height:10px;width:10px;" /></a></td>
        <td align="center" width="5%"><a id="a_del" href="#" onclick="ask(19);"><img src="http://localhost/bazarmada/pages/img/icons/cross.png" alt="Supprimer" style="height:10px;width:10px;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So how to remove the blank lines above and below the "hr" element ?

Comment: Isn't that where a `<hr>` tag is for?

Comment: Why not place a border on your cells? Something like `td { border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC; }`

Comment: But I want the rows like the four above rows ; how to do that ?

Comment: Well, you can do that like you did it the first time with the above 4 lines. Please be more specific..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default `<hr>` tag shows a horizontal line. But in your case there can be a CSS rule which override the default look. Use inspect element and check the matching CSS rule for the hr tag inside the table.

My Test [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypt8xuq/1/)

Comment: yes there was a margin-bottom style in a css file , and I ovverided that inline in the "hr" element.